# sql join joining 3 tables

Tags: sql

bit of a strange one this one...

Someone wrote a sql that in my mind shouldn't work, but it does and it also returns the correct results. I've written a simplified example, but I think it shows the point.

```
drop table #client;
drop table #transactions;
drop table #history;

create table #client (
    clientId int,
    name varchar(50)
);
create table #transactions (
    transid int,
    clientId int,
    Amount int
);
create table #history (
    transid int,
    Amount int
);

insert into #client values (1, 'User 1');
insert into #client values (2, 'User 2');
insert into #client values (3, 'User 3');

insert into #transactions values (1, 1, 50);
insert into #transactions values (2, 1, 35);
insert into #transactions values (3, 1, 25);

insert into #transactions values (4, 2, 10);
insert into #transactions values (5, 2, 50);
insert into #transactions values (6, 1, 35);
insert into #transactions values (7, 3, 25);
insert into #transactions values (8, 3, 10);

insert into #history values (1, 50);
insert into #history values (2, 35);
insert into #history values (3, 25);
insert into #history values (4, 10);
insert into #history values (5, 50);
insert into #history values (6, 35);
insert into #history values (7, 25);
insert into #history values (8, 10);

select * from #history
join #transactions on #history.transid = #transactions.transid
join #client on #transactions.clientId = #client.clientId and #history.transid = #transactions.transid
```

The last join joins 3 tables together in one join, which shouldn't work from what I know of writing SQL. Am I wrong (which may very well be the case)

Comment: You are wrong.  An `on` clause can contain references to any table/subquery that has already been defined.

Comment: hmm..didn't know that..thanks.
But if you then wanted to draw it on a diagram, there would be lines from 2 (or more) tables into 1. But I trust your statement that it is a valid join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you think it shouldn't work? 
The last bit of the query is pointless though, and you can take it out. It's a simple join on 3 tables:

```
select * from #history
join #transactions on #history.transid = #transactions.transid
join #client on #transactions.clientId = #client.clientId
```

Comment: yeah I know I could take the last join out...again my example is very simplified :)