# sql join from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

I have 3 tables

user,
wink,
messages

Im going to clarify what i want because no one seems to understand

```
SELECT wink.*,user.id,user.points,user.gender,user.firstname,user.email 
FROM wink

INNER JOIN user ON 
(wink.id_user_from_wink=user.id OR wink.id_user_to_wink=user.id)

WHERE user.id!=? 
AND (wink.id_user_from_wink=? OR wink.id_user_to_wink=?) 
AND wink.wink_confirmed='1'
```

This works exactly as i want i to. I get the desired resultset, however now i need to get the last row matching from messages table.

I have tried using LEFT JOIN but it returns to many rows.
I need to return the last matching row for each result i get from the query above

As i said, i have tried:

```
SELECT wink.*,user.id,user.points,user.gender,user.firstname,user.email 
FROM wink

INNER JOIN user ON 
(wink.id_user_from_wink=user.id OR wink.id_user_to_wink=user.id)

LEFT JOIN messages ON (messages.id_user_from_message=user.id OR messages.id_user_to_message=user.id)

WHERE user.id!=? 
AND (wink.id_user_from_wink=? OR wink.id_user_to_wink=?) 
AND wink.wink_confirmed='1'
```

results:

```
[2] => Array
        (
            [id_wink_table] => 18
            [id_user_from_wink] => 8
            [id_user_to_wink] => 6
            [wink_confirmed] => 1
            [wink_date] => 2016-07-07 07:19:09
            [id] => 8
            [points] => 4
            [gender] => 0
            [firstname] => 
            [email] => testuser1@hotmail.com
            [id_messages_table] => 5
            [id_user_from_message] => 6
            [id_user_to_message] => 8
            [message_text] => hejsan ss
            [message_confirmed] => 0
            [message_date] => 2016-07-09 02:43:59
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id_wink_table] => 18
            [id_user_from_wink] => 8
            [id_user_to_wink] => 6
            [wink_confirmed] => 1
            [wink_date] => 2016-07-07 07:19:09
            [id] => 8
            [points] => 4
            [gender] => 0
            [firstname] => 
            [email] => testuser1@hotmail.com
            [id_messages_table] => 4
            [id_user_from_message] => 6
            [id_user_to_message] => 8
            [message_text] => halluy
            [message_confirmed] => 0
            [message_date] => 2016-07-09 02:38:13
        )
```

You can see that id_user_to_message and id_user_from_message  are dublicate the only thing that differs is the message_text. So i want only the latest matching record from the messages table

EDIT:

```
SELECT wink.*,user.id,user.points,user.gender,user.firstname,user.email 
FROM wink 
INNER JOIN user 
ON (wink.id_user_from_wink=user.id OR wink.id_user_to_wink=user.id) 

**LEFT JOIN HERE returning latest message from messages table and join all rows that is returned when this left join is not used**

WHERE 
user.id!=? 
AND 
(wink.id_user_from_wink=? OR wink.id_user_to_wink=?) 
AND 
wink.wink_confirmed='1'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql join joining 3 tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801299/sql-join-joining-3-tables)

Comment: yeah but no. Ive edited to explain more what i need to do

Comment: Could you please add some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Offcourse, have edited now the result im getting and explained the result i want. Thanx in advance

Comment: You can only SELECT columns by aggregate or columns that you GROUPed BY. Write a SELECT with GROUP BY for the latest message per user then a SELECT of user etc for rows that JOIN with the 1st SELECT's users & their messages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i actually dont understand what youre saying ^^. Im not that good at sql. Could you give me an example maybe?

Should i do this in the LEFT JOIN (select ....etc)

Ive tried doing that but then nothing returns instead

Comment: I can however do a group bu user.id but then again i dont get the latest message

Comment: Note that it's exceptionally rare for DISTINCT and GROUP BY to appear together in the same query

Comment: Instead of all this verbiage, consider providing proper CREATE and INSERT statements together with the desired result

Comment: Well it is proper create and insert. I am using the table wink to link to other tables aswell. I dont understand why it is so difficult to achieve this. I could just do inner join of users and then do a query to get the latest message but its doesnt good to query the database over and over again

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
create table wink (id_wink_table int, id_user_from_wink int, id_user_to_wink int,wink_confirmed int,wink_date datetime);
insert into  wink values
(18, 8,6,1,'2016-07-07 07:19:09'),(18,8,6,1,'2016-07-07 07:19:09');

create table user (id int,points int,gender int,firstaname varchar(20), email varchar(40));
truncate table user;
insert into user values
(8,4,0,null,'testuser1hotmail.com'), (8,4,0,null,'testuser1hotmail.com');

create table messages (id_messages_table int,id_user_from_message int,id_user_to_message int,message_text varchar(20),message_confirmed int,message_date datetime);            
truncate table messages;
insert into messages values (5,6,8,'hejsan ss',0,'2016-07-09 02:43:59')

,(4,6,8,'halluy',0,'2016-07-09 02:38:13');

*/

select   * from wink;
select  * from user;
select      * from messages;
SELECT  wink.*,user.id,user.points,user.gender,user.firstaname,user.email, m.*
FROM        wink
left outer JOIN         user ON wink.id_user_from_wink = user.id OR wink.id_user_to_wink = user.id
left outer join     messages m on m.id_user_from_message=user.id OR m.id_user_to_message=user.id
where       m.id_messages_table = 
            (select max(m1.id_messages_table) from messages m1 where m.id_user_from_message=m1.id_user_from_message OR m.id_user_to_message = m1.id_user_to_message)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, although does not work as i want it to. Ive edited the post so that you may understand what id like to achieve. Im sorry if it is/was unclear

Comment: Might be to do with the test data I have set up - you could try adding or m.id_messages_table is null to the where clause and that should include any winks without messages. If that doesn't work I would be happy to look again if you can publish test data (to SO or SQL fiddle) as in my solution above with your expected results (as suggested by strawberry).