# Join three rows with one row from another table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am working on a home project. In my database I have two table called movies and category. in the movies table there are three rows named category,category_two,category_three. And in the category table there are only one row name category_name.
I wanted to join all three rows from the movies table with the row named category_table from category table.
but I do not know how to do that query.
Please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526194/mysql-inner-join-select-only-one-row-from-second-table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sql join joining 3 tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37801299/sql-join-joining-3-tables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you should do it:

```
movies table
------------
id
name


categories table
----------------
id
name


movie_categories table
----------------------
movie_id
category_id
```

Like this you can have any amount of categories for a movie. Then to get a specific movie along with its categories you can do:

```
select m.*, c.name as category_name
from movies m
left join movie_categories mc on m.id = mc.movie_id
left join categories c on c.id = mc.category_id
where m.name = 'star wars'
```